# Read file from Cloudera CDSW Project with PySpark

Tags: json, pyspark, cloudera, cdsw

I have a file sitting in my Cloudera project under "/home/cdsw/npi.json". I've tried using the following commands to use PySpark for reading from my "local" CDSW project, but can't get at it with any of the following commands. They all throw the "Path does not exist: " error

```
npi = sc.read.format("json").load("file:///home/cdsw/npi.json")

npi = sc.read.format("json").load("file:/home/cdsw/npi.json")

npi = sc.read.format("json").load("home/cdsw/npi.json")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this documentation, [Accessing Data from HDFS](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/latest/topics/cdsw_import_data.html#access_hdfs)

From terminal, copy the ***file*** from ***local file*** system to `HDFS`. Either use `-put` or `-copyFromLocal`.

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/cdsw/npi.json /destination
```

where, `/destination` is in `HDFS`.

Then, read the file in `PySpark`.

```
npi = sc.read.format("json").load("/destination/npi.json")
```

For more information:

## put

```
put [-f] [-p] [-l] <localsrc> ...  <destination>
```

> Copy files from the local file system into fs. Copying fails if the file already
>     exists, unless the -f flag is given.

Comment: You are always welcome. The URL  https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/latest/topics/cdsw_import_data.html#access_hdfs is just for the reference. Generally, you need to copy the file from `local` to `HDFS` and then access in `Spark`. Hope, it is clear.